# My RCP got stuck inside a DLL file

Tags: java, multithreading, dll, java-native-interface, rcp

I am developing a RCP program in Java, which calls some APIs from a DLL file via JNI(Java Native Interface). The dll file is also developed by myself.

An API (we call it A) is used for getting some data and it can take a long time. So I developed another API (called B here) to cancel the processing of A and return the already calculated data (e.g. maybe 50% of expected data) back to my RCP. In my RCP, I have 2 threads, one as a background thread waiting for the result from A, the other provide a dialog with a "cancel" button to allow user cancel it. When "cancel" button is pressed, B is called. In this way, B could cancel the busy A. Now the problem comes. When I click the "cancel" button , A returns no data. But it works if I run two RCPs in parallel and use one RCP to cancel the other.

It seems that I have some conflicts when use 2 threads in the same process to access JNI while works well with separated processes.

I want to know what really happens here? How is JNI shared by several threads/processes? How  to avoid getting stuck in DLL?

Thank you very much!